# unable to save model form data in database. gives patientmedinfo.errors = none and patientmedinfo.is_valid() = false

Tags: django, django-views, modelform

'I am new to Django, trying to save my form data in the database.created two model classes `PatientInfo` and `patientHist`, which is inheriting PatientInfo class. I do not understand where I am going wrong. 
 '.I am not getting any error,my tables are created in database, but no data is saving when i click on submit button'

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

     # Create your models here.
      class PatientInfo(models.Model):
          sex = (
             ('M', 'Male'),
             ('F', 'Female')
               )
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
        middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length= 30)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=sex)
        date_of_birth = models.DateField()
        height = models.FloatField()
        weight = models.FloatField()
        phone_no =models.CharField(max_length=15)


     class PatientHist(PatientInfo):
        Yes_No = (
          (True, 'Yes'),
          (False, 'No'),
           )
        Veg_nonveg =(
          (True,'Veg'),
          (False,'Non-Veg'),
           )

        diabetes = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        diabetes_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        hypertension = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        hypertension_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        obesity = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        obesity_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        pcod = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        pcod_long= models.CharField(max_length=20)
        thyroid = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        thyroid_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        heartdiease = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        heartdiease_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        liverdisease = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        liverdisease_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        kidney = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        kidney_long = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        familyhistory = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices=Yes_No)
        currentmed = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        foodhabit= models.BooleanField(default=False,choices= Veg_nonveg)
        hba1c = models.FloatField(max_length=20)
        fasting = models.FloatField(max_length=20)
        pp = models.FloatField(max_length=20)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms from .models import *


       class Patient_form(forms.ModelForm):

          class Meta:
              model = PatientInfo

              fields = "__all__"

      class PatientHistory_form(forms.ModelForm):
           class Meta:
               model = PatientHist
                 widgets = {
                          'diabetes': forms.RadioSelect,
                          'hypertension': forms.RadioSelect,
                           'obesity': forms.RadioSelect,
                           'pcod': forms.RadioSelect,
                           'thyroid': forms.RadioSelect,
                           'heartdiease': forms.RadioSelect,
                           'liverdisease': forms.RadioSelect,
                           'kidney':forms.RadioSelect,
                           'familyhistory' : forms.RadioSelect,
                           'currentmed':forms.RadioSelect,
                           'foodhabit':forms.RadioSelect,

                          }

                  fields = "__all__"
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect   
from django.http import HttpResponse  
from .forms import Patient_form,PatientHistory_form 
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect   
from django.urls import reverse 
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.
#def home(request):
    #return render(request,'home/base.html',{})

#def patient_view(request):
        #context = {}
       # context['form'] = Patient()
        #return render(request, 'home/Patient_info.html', context)

#def patienthistory_view(request):
       # context = {}
       # context['history'] = PatientHistory_form

       # return render(request, 'home/Patient_info.html', context)

def patienthistory_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        patientmedinfo = PatientHistory_form(request.POST)

        if patientmedinfo.is_valid():
            myid = patientmedinfo.save()
            myid.save()
            return HttpResponse( print(patientmedinfo.errors))
        else:
            patientmedinfo = PatientHistory_form()
            return render(request, 'home/Patient_info.html', {'form': patientmedinfo})
```

## patient_Info.html

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Patient Information{% endblock title %}

 {% block content %}


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" " method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}  <table align="center" border="0">
       <tr>
           <td><h4 align="center">Patient Information</h4></td>

           <td>{{form}}</td>
         <td><input align="center" type="submit" value="      Next-->     "></td>
     </tr>    </table>  </form>

 {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Hi, welcom to SO. Could you post the actual error to the post also (not just the title). Also include all stack trace you are getting. Also the contents of the request model would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally I found your error.

you have a field `currentmed` which is `CharField`.

But in `forms.py` you assigned `forms.RadioSelect` widget to it. So it throws an error for required field.

So just remove `'currentmed':forms.RadioSelect,` from `widget` dict of `PatientHistory_form`.

That's it.

Comment: no, still it didnt saved any data to the database after correcting in patientHistory_form.

Comment: I copied your all code and made these changes, and it worked for me !!

Comment: i am using pycharm and sqlite, dont know what was the issue i rewrite it on different project , then it worked.